# Touch friendly slide menu that follows finger?

Tags: css, html

I did an extensive search on touch friendly menu sliders that follows fingers in HTML5/CSS but can't seem to find it. (Similar to the iOS bottom volume/brightness slide menu action)

Anyone know if there's an example of such a feature in HTMl5/CSS?

Example: http://codepen.io/Edo_M/pen/cLbrt (press up arrow)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       $('.control-panel').addClass('on');
       $('.cpanel-items').addClass('show');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       $('.control-panel').removeClass('on');
       $('.cpanel-items').removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean an `<input type="range"/>`?

Comment: What I mean is this: http://codepen.io/Edo_M/pen/cLbrt (press up arrow)

Comment: It seems pretty easy to implement and you have a reference already. Simply add the appropriate class which contains a transition. You'll just have to react to the touch events accordingly. There are some [libraries](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) which simplify this for you. One thing to keep in mind, is this might interfere with the normal flow of the mobile device (on an Iphone, the settings menu may also come up with every swipe).